# Autoclaimer not working whenever it starts

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, discord.py

I am building a TikTok username claimer that integrates with Discord so you can run it, it will get a hit, post that hit on Discord, and the first to get it wins. Except whenever I run the program, it says that I am logged in except the actual claimer itself doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
import requests
import discord
import sys
class Client(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)
def tiktokclaimer():
  url = 'https://tiktok.com/@'
  with open('4s.txt') as f:
      line = f.readline().strip()
      while line:
          line = f.readline().strip()
          req = requests.get(url + line)
          if req.status_code == int(404):
            async def claimer(message):
              response = "go claim @" + line
              message.channel.send(response)
          elif req.status_code == int(403):
            async def ratelimited(message):
              response = "Ratelimited!"
              message.channel.send(response)
              sys.quit()
          elif req.status_code == int(429):
            ratelimited()
            sys.quit()
          else:
            print("An error has occurred that is not already defined. " + str(req.status_code) + " " + str(req.reason))
            break
client = Client()
client.run('MY_TOKEN')
tiktokclaimer()
```

Answer (score 0):

`client.run` is a blocking call. It blocks all code after it. Therefore `tiktokclaimer()` will never execute. You need to run your function in another thread before `client.run` using `treading` library or call it in `on_ready` event.

Comment: Tried this and it still isn't working :/